# Spring batch executing stor proc conditionally

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch, microservices

In my Spring Batch Application, I am reading, processing and then trying to write with a ItemWriter to the database using `stored procedure`:

Below is what my CSV file looks like lets say which I want to read, process and write:

```
Cob Date;Customer Code;Identifer1;Identifier2;Price
20180123;ABC LTD;BFSTACK;1231.CZ;102.00
```

My `ItemWriter`:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyDBWriter implements ItemWriter<Entity> {

    private final EntityDAO scpDao;

    public MyWriter(EntityDAO scpDao) {
        this.scpDao = scpDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Entity> items) {
        items.forEach(scpDao::insertData);
    }
}
```

My DAO implementation:

```
@Repository
public class EntityDAOImpl implements EntityDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = null;


    @PostConstruct
    private void prepareStoredProcedure() { 
        simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("loadPrice");
        //declare params
    }

    @Override
    public void insertData(Entity scp) {

        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();

        inParams.put("Identifier1", scp.getIdentifier1());
        inParams.put("Identifier2", scp.getIdentifier1());
        inParams.put("ClosingPrice", scp.getClosingPrice());
        inParams.put("DownloadDate", scp.getDownloadDate());

        simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);
    }
}
```

My Stored procedure used to update is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[loadPrice]
@Identifier1 VARCHAR(50),
@Identifier1  VARCHAR(50),
@ClosingPrice decimal(28,4),
@DownloadDate datetime

AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE p
SET ClosingPrice = @ClosingPrice,
from Prices p
join Instrument s on s.SecurityID = p.SecurityID
WHERE convert(date, @DownloadDate) = convert(date, DownloadDate)
    and s.Identifier1 = @Identifier1


if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO dbo.Prices
    (
        sec.SecurityID
        , ClosingPrice
        , DownloadDate
    )
    select sec.SecurityID
        , @ClosingPrice
        , LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DownloadDate, 112), 8)
    from dbo.Instrument sec
    WHERE sec.Identifier1 = @Identifier1
```

Give I have this setup, one of my requirement is that if I am unable to update/insert to the database using `@Identifier1` i.e. there is no `SecurityID` which matched with `Identifier1`, I need to THEN update/insert 
using the `Identifier2`. Second level match if you like.

How can I do this in my DAO `insertData()`? It is business logic and prefer in java code instead of stored proc but I am keen to look at your examples how this can be achieved.

How can I return a result of a row being updated/inserted and take decision as to whether or not to update/insert with second identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the update I would change the where clause to

```
WHERE convert(date, @DownloadDate) = convert(date, DownloadDate)
and (s.Identifier1 = @Identifier1 OR s.Identifier2 = @Identifier2)
```

and for the insert

```
WHERE sec.Identifier1 = @Identifier1 OR sec.Identifier2 = @Identifier2
```

That should work even if I haven't verified it myself. I am assuming that the given values for identifier1 and identifier2 can not match two different rows in the Instrument table.

Comment: I need `identifier1` to take precedence over `identifier2`. Is that the case with the `OR` condition? First lookup is `identiier1` ?

Comment: Yes that is how the OR clause should work but it shouldn't matter which one gets used if identifier1 and identifier2 both are used to uniquely identify the same Instrument instance.